# Why does dask throw an error when setting a String column as an index?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm reading a large CSV with dask, setting the dtypes as string and then setting it as an index:

```
dataframe = dd.read_csv(file_path, dtype={"colName": "string"}, blocksize=100e6)
dataframe.set_index("colName")
```

and it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret 'StringDtype' as a data type
```

Why does this happen? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the bug report here for an unrelated issue: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7206#issuecomment-797221227

> When constructing the dask Array's meta object, we're currently assuming the underlying array type is a NumPy array, when in this case, it's actually going to be a pandas StringArray. But unlike pandas, NumPy doesn't know how to handle a StringDtype.

Currently, changing the column type to object from string solves the issue, but it's unclear if this is a bug or an expected behavior:

```
dataframe = dd.read_csv(file_path, dtype={"colName": "object"}, blocksize=100e6)
dataframe.set_index("colName")
```